# Create a sudo user with authorized_key acess and ask to create sudo password on first login

Tags: ansible

I am on a task to create a bunch of raspberry pi. To configure these I am using ansible.
When I create the Rasbian image i am selecting the option to only allow public key access only. From the ansible I have the following task to create the users.

```yaml
- name: Ensure group "admin" exists
  ansible.builtin.group:
  name: admin
  state: present
- name: Create users
  user:
  name: "{{ item.name }}"
  groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
  state: present
  with_items: "{{ user_details }}"

- name: Add authorized_key to host
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', item.pkey) }}"
    with_items: "{{ user_details }}"
```

Here i have created a list of user and their public key location under vars:

```yaml
---
user_details:
   - { name: user_1, groups: "admin", pkey: "vars/pub_keys/user_1.pub" }
```

Everything works fine, except that when the user login via ssh eg: `user_1@192.168.0.xxx` then if they want to install something using `sudo apt install...` they are asked for a password that they don't have. Ideally these users shall not install anything on a single device as these should be handled via Ansible. But what if for some cases I would like to allow the users to install something at there own device?

My question here is can I create an admin user (as I am doing now) and at the same time give them sudo access to install with their own sudo password  ?

Comment: The usual way to fix this kind of issue is to force users to change/create their password on first login. They can then use that password they know to escalate privilege with sudo.

Comment: thanks for the comment, do you have any suggestion how to enforce that ? because I have tried to do with  "passwd" but for this i need to original sudo password ...which i dont want to give them

Comment: Change the password to a dummy one you can handover, expire it and the user will have to change it on next login.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help as i am using authorized_key, as the test based password have been disabled

Comment: As `logging in` and `install software` are two different tasks, what about allowing the login only with the ssh-key (as you do) and create some user-specific file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` to allow passwordless use of the `apt` command?